# If $f_n$ converges uniformly on compact subsets of $\Omega$ to non-constant $f$, then $f(\Omega) \subseteq \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty f_n(\Omega)$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f_n \in H(\Omega)$ be a sequence of functions converging to a function $f$ uniformly on all compact sets in a region $\Omega$.

> Show that if $f$ is not a constant function, then $f(\Omega) \subseteq \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty f_n(\Omega)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $w_0 = f(z_0) \in f(\Omega)$. Put $g_n(z) = f_n(z) - w_0$, and $g(z) = f(z) - w_0$. $g_n$ converges uniformly on compact subsets of $\Omega$ to $g$. If none of $g_n$ has a zero, then by [Hurwitz's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz%27s_theorem_%28complex_analysis%29), $g$ is either constant or doesn't have a zero. But this contradicts the assumptions. It follows that $w_0 \in f_n(\Omega)$ for some $n$ and:
$$
f(\Omega) \subset \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty f_n(\Omega)
$$

In particular, the following corollary was used from Hurwitz's theorem:

> Let $G$ be a connected, open set and $\{f_n\}$ a sequence of holomorphic functions which converge uniformly on compact subsets of $G$ to a holomorphic function $f$. If $f_n$ is not zero at any point in $G$, then $f$ is either identically zero or also is never zero.